# how to override the property Topmost = true in c#?

Tags: c#

how to override the property Topmost = true in c# ?
I want to make my form topmost of all the other application. Since another application is also using the same property, i need to override it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to play around the TopMost, if the user of your app wants your app "TopMost" then they will do that themselves.

Comment: Totally agree with @ThePower; there are *very* few things that annoy me more than software going topmost over all other applications.

Comment: This is the requirement of my application. My application controls the form to block the user playing around. The purpose of this form is forcing the user to logout and login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SetWIndowsPos() api function